# inheriting default constructor, a contradiction?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor

In C++ (inheritance subject) I read:

> A derived class automatically has a default constructor, a copy
>   constructor, and an assignment operator, like any other class. The
>   compiler-generated default constructor calls the base class default
>   constructor

But on the other hand:

> The base class constructors are not inherited We must explicitly
>   define any constructors the derived class needs

**1)** what does it mean to inherit a constructor?

**2)** isn't what is written above a contradiction?

I hope to add some examples if possible to help me understand.

Answer (score 2):

"The base class constructors are not inherited" means that any constructor defined in a class `Base` is not available for a derived class `Derived` unless it is re-defined in `Derived`. This is also valid for the default constructor. But, "A derived class automatically has a default constructor" says that the compiler will automatically generate a default constructor, just as it does for every class. So the compiler will re-define a default constructor in a derived class; it is still not inherited.

The only thing is that "We must explicitly define any constructors the derived class needs", if there is no context under which this statement shall hold, seems wrong. There are definitely constructors available in a derived class that have not been defined *explicitely*. This can be shown easily by defining a derived class without any *explicit* constructor:

```
struct Base {
    Base () { std::cout << "in default constructor of Base; not inherited, but still called." << std::endl; };
};

struct Derived : public Base {
   // no explicitly defined constructor...
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
}
```

Output:

```
in default constructor of Base; not inherited, but still called.
```

So I'd tend to say that the statement "... We must explicitly define any constructors the derived class needs" you cited is either not precise, not shown in full context, or wrong.

Comment: But why the say "We must explicitly define any constructors the derived class needs"

Comment: Because _The base class constructors are not inherited_. If you don't define them, nobody will define them. The compiler won't define constructors from the base class.

Comment: You are right, the "explicitly" sounds like contradiction; I think "they" omitted a "the derived class needs, unless these constructors are implicitly defined by the compiler". BTW: who is "they"? Is it some normative source? –

Comment: But why I need to write a constructor while "A derived class automatically has a default constructor", what is its job? I think it calls the constructor of the parent class

Comment: Ok thanks, But what's the difference between calling the constructor of the parent and inheriting it? it's the same I think...

Comment: @smith Again you ask about the difference between two completely different things. You should know what it means to call a function (the constructor is a function). Here is the description of [inheritance](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

```
struct s {
    s() : s_str("my string") {}; // default constructor
    std::string s_str;
};

struct d : s {
    std::string d_str;
};
```

If `d` didn't have any members that needed construction, the default constructor would simply construct `s` with `s::s()` which superficially looks like inheritance (and could be implemented that way). But when you add data members to the derived class, that won't work.

The default constructor for `s` constructs `s_str` with the text `"my string"`.

If `s::s()` was inherited in `d` it wouldn't know about `d_str`, so wouldn't construct it. So it's not inherited.

Instead, the compiler generates a default constructor for `d` that constructs `d_str` with the default constructor for `std::string` and constructs the `s` base with `s::s()`.